# Calculate the difference in hours from now and next workday's 9am

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

How do I calculate the difference in hours from now and the next workday's 9am?

If NOW() is Thursday 6pm and the next workday is Friday, the function would then return 15.

If NOW() is Friday 5pm and the next workday is Monday, the result is then 64.

What's the formula to do that? For simplicity's sake, I don't need to take into account holidays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of hours will be simply the next business day at 9:00 AM minus the starting time (formatted as [hh]:mm to allow the display of >24 hour periods). The trick will be getting the number representing the next business day at 9:00 AM correct.

[image: Hours till next business day]

The formula in B2 is,

`=WORKDAY(A2,1*(HOUR(A2)>9))+TIME(9,0,0)`

This makes the formula in C2,

`=(WORKDAY(A2,1*(HOUR(A2)>9))+TIME(9,0,0))-A2`

Excel treats a *boolean* FALSE as zero when used mathematically. A TRUE is a one. By checking if the time of the start date/time is less than the current day, an additional day is not added until after 9:00 AM.

Comment: I believe this can be simplified.  Say A2 is your start date/time.  C2 is: =24*(WORKDAY(A2,1)-A2)+9.  Format the result as a number.  Workday() returns a time of 0:00 AM on the next workday.

Comment: Fixer, if you can add your answer, I'll mark your answer as correct. Otherwise, I'll mark Jeeped's answer as correct.

Comment: @fixer1234 - I prefer to keep times as times; especially so for future calculations which this formula seems to indicate for the following reasons. **a)** Converting to an integer (or double) with *1* representing an hour and not a day leaves values like 12 hours and 35 minutes (12:35) as 12.5833333. **b)** to use in a time calculation, you must remember to divide the result by 24. **c)** using two number systems for the same values in a single worksheet/workbook just gets confusing.

Comment: @chuacw - This formula may have slightly less characters and functions but be wary of using more than a single number system in a worksheet. IMHO, converting values like *hours* to a system where 1 represents an hour and not a day is simply more headache than it is worth. I've seen timecard spreadsheets where some idiot with an MBA thought it would be smart to convert all the hours to integers. They were a rat's nest of confusion and inaccuracy. At a minimum, pick one number systems and stick with it and do not bounce between the two.

Comment: @chuacw - Jeeped deserves the credit.  There is nothing wrong with his answer; I just offered a shorter version.  The rational in his comment above for the additional functions is good.